# Error con subreporte en ireport

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

Necesito ayuda...estoy haciendo un informe con ireport y netbeans invocandolo desde programa java...todo bien al compilar y ejecutar...el problema se presenta cuando inserto un subreporte...pasa la compilacion pero al momento de ejecutar me entrega este error....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRPrintBand.addOffsetElements(JRPrintBand.java:101)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.addSubElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:623)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.fillElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:600)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:406)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:352)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBackground(JRVerticalFiller.java:1804)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at PruebaRep.Main.main(Main.java:291)
```

Comment: Hola Claudia, el mensaje te dice que hay una variable que no fue instanciada, sin ver tu código no hay forma de que te podamos ayudar, puedes editar tu pregunta y agregarlo a la misma.

Comment: Oka gracias...subiré el código

Comment: No pude agregar el código no se como adjuntarlo porque me da error :(

Comment: Si el código es muy largo, agregale texto (un saludo, o cualquier cosa) ya que detecta que hay mucho código y poca explicación, si tienes una clase **JRPrintBand**, es probablemente la que está generando el error, si es así, sube solo esa.

Comment: Esa clase yo no la he invocado....no se como verla...sorry soy principiante de hecho es mi primer programa en java

Comment: Debe ser una clase interna de Ireport, porfi, sube tu método **main**, y si puedes la clase **Main** completa.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné....le indiqué que uso un data source vacío ..ahora tengo otro problema jajajaja....me aparece solo el primer registro del detalle :(

Comment: Bien que lo solucionaste, podrías agregar tu código, y publicar tu respuesta explicando como soluciona el problema, de esa forma estarías ayudando a otros que se encuentren con el mismo problema, y tal vez te ganes unos puntitos de reputación, para el nuevo problema, te sugiero hacer una nueva pregunta.